# Highcharts: Align two series horizontally to the same x-axis which are in opposite sides

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart which has two series with two yAxises. And both of them share the same xAxis. But I need these two series to be on the opposite sides (one at the bottom and the other at the top). I can achieve this by adding `reversed: true` in the options of one yAxis. But now I'm having an issue in aligning both series in one line horizontally. I don't mind them getting overlapped. After searching I found out that by putting minPadding and maxPadding I can remove this space, but it didn't work. Is this possible in highchart?

I want it to be something like below,

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to align like this? Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
              'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      },
    yAxis: [
    {
        opposite: true
    }, 
    {   // Secondary yAxis
        reversed: true
    }
    ],
    series: [{
        name: 'S1',
        type: 'column',
        data: [40, 60, 50],
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0
    }, {
        name: 'S2',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        xAxis: 0,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        data: [30, 20, 10]

    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `grouping`:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  grouping: false
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4945/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping